# Произведение членов последовательности с++

Tags: c++

Дана последовательность :
1, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 9/5, ... 
Необходимо вычислить произведение от 1 до n члена последовательности.

Подсказку подкиньте как решить

Я вот попытался с помощью общей формулы решить, но выдает не те числа в результате

```
cin >> n
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

        a_i = ((2 * i) - 1) / i;

        result = result * a_i;

    }
```

Comment: Потребуется освоить цикл for. Кроме того, не забыть о том, что нужно выполнять вещественное деление, а не целочисленное

Comment: вы издеваетесь??? автор, зачем вы выбрали ит профессию, если самую элементарную программу написать не можете и даже не пытаетесь

Comment: Откуда столько агрессии? Свой код я привел, спросил почему выдает левые ответы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем-то в приведенном Вами коде почти все правильно. Однако следует привести переменную `i` к вещественному типу (`float` или `double`) и инициализировать переменную `result`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    float result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        result *= (2*float(i) - 1)/float(i);
    }

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```